# Multiline UILabels With Auto layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have been trying for the last 2 days to get a UITableViewCell to do the following manual calculation.

```
CGFloat availableWidthForValueLabel = availableWidth * 0.7f;
CGSize valueLabelFitSize = [_valueLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(availableWidthForValueLabel, MAXFLOAT)];
_valueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(availableWidth - valueLabelFitSize.width, 0, valueLabelFitSize.width, valueLabelFitSize.height);

CGFloat availableWidthForKeyLabel = availableWidth - CGRectGetWidth(_valueLabel.frame);
CGSize keyLabelFitSize = [_keyLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(availableWidthForKeyLabel, MAXFLOAT)];
CGFloat keyLabelX = CGRectGetMinX(_valueLabel.frame) - keyLabelFitSize.width;
```

I have two  multi-lined labels (key, value) in a view.

The value is anchored to the right of the view the Key is anchored to the left of the view with right aligned text.

I want to evaluate the values width/height first with a maximum width of 0.7 * view width then want the key to take up the rest of the available space in the view.

This works fine for single lines labels, but as not for multi-lined labels.

I have tried setting the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the value label in both the updateConstraints and layoutSubview in the **cell** but what seems to happen is the hight of the cell grow incorrectly so big gaps appear in the cell.

```
- (void)updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];

    // value width
    CGFloat width = ceil(self.keyValueSection.bounds.size.width * kValueMaxLenghtOfParentView);
    if (self.valueLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != width )
    {
        self.valueLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;
    }

    // dec width
    if (!self.decSection.hidden)
    {
        width = ceil(self.holderSection.bounds.size.width * kDecMaxLengthOfParentView);
        if (self.decLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != width )
        {
            self.decLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;
        }
    }

    // key width
    width = floor(self.keyValueSection.bounds.size.width - kKeyValueGap - self.valueLabel.bounds.size.width);

    if(self.keyLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != width)
    {
        self.keyLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;
    }
}
```

I have tried everything I can find on the web and it all nearly works. I have tried setting the hugging and compression ratio but.

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be the most elegant solution, i have fond a way to do what i want.

I use Autolayout to position the labels using constraints for vertical spacing >=0 top and bottom and centre Y alignment. I then specific the constraints for leading and trailing between the labels.

I then give each label a height and width constraint, and use the sizeTofit method to workout what the constants should be and update them when I set the labels text/atttributed text properties.

```
self.keyLabel.text = model.lineKey;
if ([model.lineValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    self.valueLabel.text = model.lineValue;
}
else if ([model.lineValue isKindOfClass:[NSAttributedString class]])
{
    self.valueLabel.attributedText = model.lineValue;
}
else
{
    self.valueLabel.text = nil;
    self.valueLabel.attributedText = nil;
}

self.keyValueGap.constant = kKeyValueGap;
CGFloat availableWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.keyValueSection.bounds);

CGFloat availableWidthForValueLabel = availableWidth * 0.5f;
CGSize valueLabelFitSize = [self.valueLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(availableWidthForValueLabel, MAXFLOAT)];

self.valueHeight.constant = valueLabelFitSize.height;
self.valueWidth.constant = valueLabelFitSize.width;

CGFloat availableWidthForkeyLabel = availableWidth - valueLabelFitSize.width - kKeyValueGap;


CGSize keyLabelFitSize = [self.keyLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(availableWidthForkeyLabel, MAXFLOAT)];

self.keyHeight.constant = keyLabelFitSize.height;
self.keyWidth.constant = availableWidthForkeyLabel;
```

If anyone else has any better ideas :)  -  i would love to hear them as i do not like manually calculations while using autolayout